# How to get the a running script's root directory, when ran as a Scheduled Job?

Tags: powershell

The automatic variables $PSScriptRoot and $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path are not populated, when a script is ran as a Scheduled Job. Does anyone know of a workaround?

## Example

```
Register-ScheduledJob -Name TestScheduledJob -ScriptBlock {
    '$PSScriptRoot = [' + $PSScriptRoot + ']'
    '$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path = [' + $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path + ']'
}

Start-Job -DefinitionName TestScheduledJob | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

## Result

```
$PSScriptRoot = []
$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path = []
```

One hack I have thought of is, making the path a parameter to the script.

Comment: `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`?

Comment: `$Path=$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path    
$scriptPath=split-path $Path -Parent  
$scriptPath+" "+$Path|Out-File $scriptpath\Log9999.txt  `
No. File is creating in the root directory (C:\)  , but he is empty. Help)

Comment: have you considered using `Start in` to specify working directory?

Comment: NO.I was simply amazed.How was that possible?

Comment: Let me just double check: How is the first bit (all of that Register-ScheduleJob stuff) being run, from a script or interactively? And that second bit - test2.ps1 contains `$PSScriptRoot | Out-File "$PSScriptRoot\Log9999.txt"`?

Comment: The second script run via -ScheduledJob and $PSScriptRoot is not defined there.